# MySQL calculating max value across multiple columns/tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some mysql tables that I would like to extract some information from, the tables are:

- Videos - represents a video with a score.
- Tags - contains a global list of tags.
- VideoTags - creates an association between a Video and a Tag.

And in addition to Videos resources, I also have Pictures resources:

- Pictures - represents a picture with a score.
- PictureTopic - creates an association between a picture and a topic.

And a Users table for ownership of the Videos and Pictures

- Users - can own Videos and Pictures

What I want to do is find the videos or pictures with the highest points for each tag/topic. There are many videos and pictures with the same tag/topic, but my result set will have the
same number of rows as there are tags/topics. The end goal is to have a list of the best video or picture (by points) for each unique tag (tags being a topic prefixed with a hash).

With the solution from a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778329/mysql-data-extraction-from-3-tables-joins-and-max)
I am able to get all of the videos with the highest points for each tag.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Tags.content,2) as topic_id, Videos.id as resource_id, 'video' as resource_type, Videos.owner_id as resource_owner_id, Videos.points FROM Videos JOIN (
  SELECT   VideoTags.tag_id, MAX(points) points
  FROM     Videos JOIN VideoTags ON Videos.id = VideoTags.video_id
  GROUP BY VideoTags.tag_id
) t USING (points) JOIN Tags ON t.tag_id = Tags.id and Tags.content LIKE "#%"
```

I can also (kinda) get the pictures with the highest points for each topic with this expression:

```
SELECT   PictureTopic.topic_id, Pictures.id as resource_id, 'picture' as resource_type, Pictures.owner_id as resource_owner_id, MAX(points) points
FROM     Pictures JOIN PictureTopic ON Pictures.id = PictureTopic.picture_id
GROUP BY PictureTopic.topic_id
```

What I want is to get the picture or video with the highest points for each tag/topic, with the following edge cases handled:

- if there are more than one pictures or videos for a given topic (i.e. they have the same high score), then defer to the resource owner's points, if they both have the same points too (unlikely) then both resources can be in the result set (unless the resources are owned by the same User, in which case there should only be one result in the result set).
- if the points for a video or picture are less than 20, exlude that resource from the result set.

As a software dev whose uses Grails a lot I like to lean on object relational mapping and hence my sql skills are lame. The best I can do so far is to bring the results of the two selects together:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Tags.content,2) as topic_id, Videos.id as resource_id, 'video' as resource_type, Videos.owner_id as resource_owner_id, Videos.points FROM Videos JOIN (
  SELECT   VideoTags.tag_id, MAX(points) points
  FROM     Videos JOIN VideoTags ON Videos.id = VideoTags.video_id
  GROUP BY VideoTags.tag_id
) t USING (points) JOIN Tags ON t.tag_id = Tags.id and Tags.content LIKE "#%"
UNION
SELECT   PictureTopic.topic_id, Pictures.id as resource_id, 'picture' as resource_type, Pictures.owner_id as resource_owner_id, MAX(points) points
FROM     Pictures JOIN PictureTopic ON Pictures.id = PictureTopic.picture_id
GROUP BY PictureTopic.topic_id
```

But unfortunately that's not even getting the high scoring pictures as expected. As can be seen on sqlfiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6650d/1 )

The output from this query is:

```
TOPIC_ID    RESOURCE_ID         RESOURCE_TYPE   RESOURCE_OWNER_ID   POINTS
topic-1     owner-x-video-a     video           owner-x             20
topic-2     owner-y-video-m     video           owner-y             44
topic-1     owner-j-pic-1       picture         owner-j             50
topic-3     owner-k-pic-2       picture         owner-k             22
```

But I would expect this row too:

```
TOPIC_ID    RESOURCE_ID         RESOURCE_TYPE   RESOURCE_OWNER_ID   POINTS
topic-3     owner-l-pic-3       picture         owner-l             22
```

And after the edge case of equal high scores and a score threshold I would like to see:

```
TOPIC_ID    RESOURCE_ID         RESOURCE_TYPE   RESOURCE_OWNER_ID   POINTS
topic-1     owner-j-pic-1       picture         owner-j             50
topic-2     owner-y-video-m     video           owner-y             44
topic-3     owner-l-pic-3       picture         owner-l             22
```

Here's the schema and sample data for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `id`       VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `points`   DOUBLE      NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Engine=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Videos`;
CREATE TABLE `Videos` (
  `id` varchar(24) NOT NULL default '',
  `owner_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL default '',
  `points` DOUBLE NOT NULL default 0
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tags`;
CREATE TABLE `Tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(32) NOT NULL default ''
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `VideoTags`;
CREATE TABLE `VideoTags` (
  `video_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL default '',
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Pictures`;
CREATE TABLE `Pictures` (
  `id` varchar(24) NOT NULL default '',
  `owner_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL default '',
  `points` DOUBLE NOT NULL default 0
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PictureTopic`;
CREATE TABLE `PictureTopic` (
  `picture_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` varchar(31) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Users (id, points) VALUES ('owner-x', 0);
INSERT INTO Users (id, points) VALUES ('owner-y', 0);
INSERT INTO Users (id, points) VALUES ('owner-j', 0);
INSERT INTO Users (id, points) VALUES ('owner-k', 5);
INSERT INTO Users (id, points) VALUES ('owner-l', 14);

INSERT INTO Videos (id,owner_id,points) VALUES
  ('owner-x-video-a','owner-x', 20),
  ('owner-x-video-b','owner-x', 15),
  ('owner-y-video-k','owner-y', 12),
  ('owner-y-video-l','owner-y', 17),
  ('owner-y-video-m','owner-y', 44);

INSERT INTO Tags (id, content) VALUES
  (111, '#topic-1'),
  (222, '#topic-2');

INSERT INTO VideoTags (video_id,tag_id) VALUES
  ('owner-x-video-a',111),
  ('owner-x-video-b',111),
  ('owner-y-video-k',111),
  ('owner-y-video-l',222),
  ('owner-y-video-m',222);

INSERT INTO Pictures (id, owner_id, points) VALUES ('owner-j-pic-1','owner-j', 50);
INSERT INTO Pictures (id, owner_id, points) VALUES ('owner-k-pic-2','owner-k', 22);
INSERT INTO Pictures (id, owner_id, points) VALUES ('owner-l-pic-3','owner-l', 22);

INSERT INTO PictureTopic (picture_id, topic_id) VALUES ('owner-j-pic-1','topic-1');
INSERT INTO PictureTopic (picture_id, topic_id) VALUES ('owner-k-pic-2','topic-3');
INSERT INTO PictureTopic (picture_id, topic_id) VALUES ('owner-l-pic-3','topic-3');
```

Any pointers on how to best extract this information? Cheers :)

Comment: Can you please clearify your situations i am unable to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOPIC_ID, RESOURCE_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE, RESOURCE_OWNER_ID, POINTS
FROM (( SELECT pt.topic_id AS TOPIC_ID,
            p.id AS RESOURCE_ID,
            'picture' AS RESOURCE_TYPE,
            p.owner_id AS RESOURCE_OWNER_ID,
            p.points AS POINTS,
            u.points AS user_points
        FROM Pictures AS p
        INNER JOIN PictureTopic AS pt
        ON p.id = pt.picture_id
        INNER JOIN Users AS u
        ON p.owner_id = u.id)
        UNION ALL
    (   SELECT SUBSTR(t.content, 1), v.id, 'video', v.owner_id, v.points, u.points
        FROM Videos AS v
        INNER JOIN VideoTags AS vt
        ON v.id = vt.video_id
        INNER JOIN Tags AS t
        ON vt.tag_id = t.id
        INNER JOIN Users AS u2
        ON v.owner_id = u2.id)
        ORDER BY POINTS DESC, user_points DESC) AS h
GROUP BY TOPIC_ID
ORDER BY TOPIC_ID ASC
```

This query takes use of [**INNER JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), [**subqueries**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html), [**UNION**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), [**GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and the inofficial MySQL assumption that `GROUP BY` will return the 1st row based on `ORDER BY POINTS DESC`

Comment: That's great thanks @robin-castlin, any thoughts on how I could defer to the User A and B's points to find a high score when user A's Video and User B's Picture both have the same points? As is the case in the sample data for Users 'owner-k' and 'owner-l' i.e. they both have a Picture with 22 points, hence the picture belonging to 'owner-l' should be the highestest scoring as 'owner-l' has more points in the Users table than 'owner-k'.

Comment: Simply `JOIN` in the `Users` table with the 2 `SELECTs` and update `ORDER BY` with `user_points DESC`. Above query is updated.

Comment: Thanks Robin! Your cheque is in the mail ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is The query for videos

```
select 
    t.content as `TOPIC-ID`,
    vt.video_id as `RESOURCE-ID`,   
    'video' as `RESOURCE-TYPE`,
    vt.owner_id as `RESOURCE-OWNER-ID`,
    vt.MaxPoints

from tags as t
inner join 
    (SELECT 
        vt.tag_id,
        vt.video_id,
        MAX(v.points) as MaxPoints,
        v.id,
        v.owner_id  
    FROM videotags as vt
    left join videos as v on v.id = vt.video_id
    group by vt.tag_id

    ) as vt on vt.tag_id = t.id

union all
SELECT 
    topic_id as `TOPIC-ID`,
    picture_id as `RESOURCE-ID`,
    'picture' as `RESOURCE-TYPE`,
    p.owner_id as `RESOURCE-OWNER-ID`,
    p.points as MaxPoints
FROM picturetopic
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id , owner_id , points FROM pictures) as p on p.id = picturetopic.picture_id
```